# PHP&MySQL signin form-error with accessing database table

Tags: mysql

I want my users to be able to sign in using their accounts, so I created an html form and a php file that will communicate with mySQL database.
The php code is supposed to check whether the username and password are correct and exist in the database. If so the user is granted access. I am thinking such algorithm:

```
<?php

//connection_start
$mysqli = new mysqli('mysql3.000webhost.com','a4305565_os','******','a4305565_users');

//check_connection
if($mysqli->connect_error){
    die("Connection error (check_connection): " . $mysqli->connect_errno . " : " . $mysqli->connect_error );
    exit();
}

//check_if_account_exists

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` where `username` = '$_POST[form_username]' AND `password` = '$_POST[form_password]'") or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error());

//verification
if(!empty($row['username']) AND !empty($row['password'])){
    echo "SUCCESSFULLY SIGNED IN.";
}else{
    die("Your are not registered yet.");
}

//Connection_end
$mysqli->close();

?>
```

But when I test the code on my web host, it is giving me an error on line 14 saying that I

> do not have access to the database "a4305565_users" with password=NO

or something like that.

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Your user don't have any rights on *a4305565_users* schema.
Edit your user privileges to give him the rights to use this schema.

Also it's kind of weird that you are creating a schema named "users", this sounds more like a table name.

And, as a word of advice, you should hash your users password, it's a very bad practice to store them in plain text.
Also, you can salt your hashes.

Look at this : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)